# What's a good free hosted wiki with source code highlighting?

Tags: wiki, syntax-highlighting

I'm currently using Google Sites to publicly document my dev workflows and commands.  However, Google Sites does not have a source code syntax highlighting system in place.  Is there a free alternative to Google Sites with syntax highlighting?  The solution I'm looking for need to meet the following requirements:

1. Free hosted service
2. At least 100 MB of space for free users like Google Sites
3. Has a nice editor with the whole web 2.0 feel and look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just googled for you ... maybe http://bitbucket.org will work for you. they have a free plan with 1gig, 1 Private repository, unlimited public repositories, Wiki, Issue tracker, Code Highlighting (see for supported languages) http://pygments.org/languages/)

Comment: Github has a wiki too, I guess I'll give those source hosting sites a try.